# Cannot uninstall android app

Tags: android, apk

I have a lot of research about this, but there's no question that matched with this issue. I have installed an android app. Then if I uninstall it, its just showing a **pop up** the application's `icon`. I have also tried to go to `security` setting and the `administrator`, but the application is not there. What happen to that?

Comment: What app did you install? Can you also show screenshots?

Comment: hm. my own. just installed it via `android studio`.

Comment: http://techbeasts.com/how-to-installuninstall-applications-using-android-adb/ Have you tried usb debugging mode?

Comment: what does it say when you uninstall the app??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know package name (something like *com.company.app*) you can try plugging into a PC with **adb** and issuing `adb uninstall <package name>`

Comment: Where do I issue the `adb uninstall <package name>` ?

Comment: If you have Android Studio, there is a Terminal tab on the bottom. You can issue adb commands here

Comment: I tried it, but there's an error. saying `"adb is not recognized as an internal or external command..."`

Comment: You need to download and install adb. You can go to SDK Manager in Android Studio and install Google Drivers USB // or you can check this thread for adb : https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979

Comment: Done!  This is the solution

Comment: Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall it using **adb** (Android Debug Bridge), a swiss-knife tool from the Android SDK.

First, you need to know the SDK folder location: In Android Studio, go to Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager, and get the location from "Android SDK Location".

Then, go to the Terminal tab on the bottom, and type:

```
cd <Android SDK Location>
cd platform-tools
```

That will leave you in the folder that contains the adb tool.

Finally, to uninstall the application from your device, type in the Terminal:

```
adb uninstall <package name>
```